# gSOAP SSL - converting existing code to ssl

Tags: c++, ssl, wsdl, gsoap

The earlier Version of this question got no Response, so I'm updating the entire Thing:

I have a test gSOAP Client and server on my machine. The client does an MTOM upload of various files to the server.
When attempting to convert the code to ssl I get the following error:

The server reports:

```
"SSL_ERROR_SSL
error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher"
```

The client reports:

```
An SSL error occured
SOAP 1.2 fault SOAP-ENV:Receiver [no subcode]
"SSL_ERROR_SSL
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure"
Detail: SSL_connect error in tcp_connect()
```

it runs without the "SSL" option. Can someone advise me as to what I'm doing wrong?

Applicable client code -

```
if(fSSL)
    soap_ssl_init();
. . .
soap_init1(&my_soap, SOAP_ENC_MTOM);  /* Enable MTOM */
. . .
if(fSSL)
{
    if (soap_ssl_client_context(&my_soap,
        SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION + SOAP_TLSv1_2,
        NULL, // client keyfile
        NULL, // passphrase for keyfile
        NULL, // certified authority certificate
        NULL, // directory for trusted certificates
        NULL))// random data for seed
        {
            soap_print_fault(&my_soap, stderr);
            ...
        }
}
...
long gsoap_status = soap_call___ns1__upload(&my_soap, endpoint.c_str(), NULL, &upload_parms, &upload_response);
```

Applicable server code -

```
if(fSSL)
    soap_ssl_init();
. . .
soap_init1(&my_soap, SOAP_ENC_MTOM);  /* Enable MTOM */
. . .
if(fSSL)
{
    if (soap_ssl_server_context(&my_soap,
        SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION + SOAP_TLSv1_2, // per EMAIL - option 1
        NULL,    // Keyfile - required for authentication
        NULL,    // passphrase
        NULL,    // password to read Keyfile
        NULL,    // optional cacert file
        NULL,    // DH Filename or DH key len bits
        NULL,    // Randfile
        NULL))   // optional server identification (enable SSL session cache)
        {
            soap_print_fault(&my_soap, stderr);
            exit(0);
        }
}
. . .
my_soap.connect_timeout = 20; 
my_soap.send_timeout = 60; 
my_soap.recv_timeout = 60; 
if(!soap_valid_socket(soap_bind(&my_soap, NULL, port, 100)))
{
    soap_print_fault(&my_soap, stderr);
    exit(1);
}
fprintf(stderr, "Bind to port %d successful\n", port);

// server loop starts
for (;;)
    printf("server loop sta\n");
    int t_socket = soap_accept(&my_soap);
    struct soap* t_soap = 0;   
    t_soap = soap_copy(&my_soap);       
    if(fSSL)
    {
        if(soap_ssl_accept(&my_soap))   <------ FAILS HERE
        {
            printf("NOT Accepting (ssl) socket=%d connection from IP: %d.%d.%d.%d ...", t_socket, 
                        (int)my_soap.ip>>24&0xFF,
                        (int)my_soap.ip>>16&0xFF,
                        (int)my_soap.ip>>8&0xFF,
                        (int)my_soap.ip&0xFF);            
            soap_print_fault(&my_soap, stderr);
            soap_destroy(&my_soap);
            soap_end(&my_soap);
            continue;
        }
    }
    . . .
    if(soap_serve(&my_soap))
        ...
```

Server Console output:

```
Bind to port 8080 successful
server loop sta
NOT Accepting (ssl) socket=364 connection from IP: 127.0.0.1 ...Error 30 fault is internal [no subcode]
"SSL_ERROR_SSL
error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher"
Detail: SSL_accept() failed in soap_ssl_accept()
```

Comment: This error is typical produced when the client uses HTTP instead of HTTPS to open the connection. Are you sure the client uses a HTTPS URL with "https://..."?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on this now. I think the errors that you are seeing are because most/all distributions of openSSL do not support anonymous authentication any longer due to man in the middle attacks.  A self-signed certificate on the server-side may be the only way to make these examples work.

Comment: Sorry, I havn't been active enough with this - the Certificate Authority and the Certificate were incorrectly configured. This had to do with chaining the Certificate and that it was configured with an ancient Version of openSSL. The current Version has plenty of diagnostics, tests and Docs to explain it all.